# How do I keep WPF Button Template from changing All Buttons When Moused Over?

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, button

I am working with a custom template for a WPF template.  For the most part it is working, however, when I mouse-over a button it changes the text color for all the buttons on the same screen, which is unintended.

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
      Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
      Value="{DynamicResource ButtonFocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border TextBlock.Foreground="{DynamicResource AlternateFontColor}"
                        TextBlock.FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                        TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold"                            
                        x:Name="Border"
                        CornerRadius="0"
                        BorderThickness="2" >
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ColorBackgroundColor}" />
                    </Border.Background>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.0" />
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"
                              To="Pressed" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                  (SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlBorderMouseOverColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                  (SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlBorderMouseOverColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                      TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"

                                      >                                        

                    </ContentPresenter>

                </Border>
                <!-- Triggers -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Style declaration as

```
 <Style  x:Key="buttonStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
```

and assign style to buttons if they have to be styled as

```
 <Button Style="{DynamicResource buttonStyle}">H2</Button>
```

Other buttons won't inherit style after declaring x:Key

Comment: It's not that I don't want other buttons to inherit the style, I do. It's that when I mouse over one button, all of the other button the font color (foreground) changes for all buttons on the same page.  It should only fire for the button that is moused over, not all of them